# Trying to hide .htaccess file

Tags: file, .htaccess, hide

I'm trying to hide my .htaccess file so everyone can't just read it out in their browser.

My .htaccess file is located here: http://businessgame.be/.htaccess
as you can see you can still just read it out.

I tried adding the following:

```
# secure htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

and also

```
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

But none of it seems to work. This is really weird. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: What operating system are you on?

Comment: Are you sure you're using Apache?

Comment: It's a linux server running apache. The rewrite conditions are working so why would htaccess only work partly?

Comment: I get `403 Forbidden` when trying to view that URL. Seems fine to me.

Comment: Yeah I couldn't figure it out via .htaccess so I just configured it via the Apache server to hide it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just follow this sample code for .htaccess files...

```
<Files ~ "^\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$">
deny from all
</Files>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
</IfModule>
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(yourwebsite.com)(:80)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
DirectoryIndex index.php       
order deny,allow
Header unset ETag
FileETag None

<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|png|gif|js|css|ico|swf)$">
Header set cache-Control: "max-age=572800, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
```

This would more help for us.....

other wise it will help you...

```
  <Files ~ "\.html$">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
Satisfy All
</Files>
<Files ~ "\.css$">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
Satisfy All
</Files>
```

Else its will working well.. i `ll checked this code in my website.

```
  Options +FollowSymlinks
 # Prevent Directoy listing 
Options -Indexes
# Prevent Direct Access to files
# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/ 
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Thank u....for giving opportunity post for you...

Answer (score 4):

This is my serv config, and it work, you should try the same :

```
# secure htaccess file
    <files .htaccess>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </files>
    <FilesMatch "\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$">
        Order Allow,Deny
        Deny from all
    </FilesMatch>
```